# Scala MongoDB aggregate group and match query

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query, aggregate, mongo-scala-driver

I want a query that will take the latest version out of each document, and check if some given string (`applicationId`) is in the list `allowedApplications`.

documents example:

```
{
    "applicationId" : "y...",
    "allowedApplications": ["x..."],
    "name" : "some-name",
    "version" : 3
}
{
    "applicationId" : "y...",
    "allowedApplications": ["x..."],
    "name" : "some-name",
    "version" : 2
}
{
    "applicationId" : "x...",
    "allowedApplications": ["y..."],
    "name" : "some-other-name",
    "version" : 1
}
```

So the MongoDB query is:

```
db.getCollection('..').aggregate(
[
    { "$match": { "allowedApplications": "x..." }},
    {"$group": { "_id": "$name", "version": { "$max": "$version" }}}
]
   )
```

And the query will output the name and version (I'll perhaps add the `allowedApplications` later).

I'm trying now to write this in Scala's mongodb driver.

I tried a bunch of stuff, for example:

```
collection
            .aggregate(List(
                `match`(equal("allowedApplications", "x..")),
                group("$name", addToSet("version", addToSet("$max", "¢version")))
            )
            )
```

But couldn't get it to work.

Using Scala 2.13.1 and mongo-scala-driver 4.1.0.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
collection
            .aggregate(List(
                `match`(equal("allowedApplications", "x...")),
                group("$name", max("version", "$version"))
            )
```

The order isn't quite the same, but just use the function in the accumulator field.